# Reading From Stdin Twice in C

Tags: c, input, buffer, stdin, stdio

```
    int getLineCount() {
        int ret = 0;
        char c;
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
            if (c == '\n')
                ret++;
        return ret + 1;
    }

    void fill(char *WORD) {
        int charIndex = 0;
        char c;
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
           *(WORD + charIndex++) = c;
        }
    }

    int main() {
        int lineNum = getLineCount();
        char *WORD = (char*)calloc(lineNum * 18,sizeof(int));

        fill(WORD);
        return 0;
    }
```

Here is the part of my code, and my question is(as you can see):

I'm trying to read stdin's content twice, but after the **getLineCount** function, it stays at the EOF and I can't read it again in **fill** function.

Im taking stdin from the user with this command in Linux;

```
$./output < text_file.txt
```

Is there any way to roll back stdin to starting character? If not, how can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `man fseek`. **Update**: Oops. It's `stdin`.. no you can't. It's not seekable.

Comment: @user3121023: It is bad style to assume you can rewind `stdin`.

Comment: @user3121023 Interesting... Does it really work?

Comment: Why not store the previous value read? That's what variables are for.

Comment: @user3121023 You just saved my life. Thanks! You can write it as response, so I can mark it as solution.

Comment: I agree with @Olaf in that it would be bad to assume you can rewind `stdin`. To those questioning the ability to rewind it at all... if it's a terminal then of course you cannot, but if the channel is to a device that normally permits rewinding then certainly you can. The problem is you often cannot control what device type `stdin` is - hence it being bad practice to assume the `rewind()`/`fseek()` can be done here.

Comment: @DoğaCanYanıkoğlu I strongly recommend you to consider the other comments rather than the dup answer..

Comment: @user3121023: No, that is bad practice as mah elaborated. There are better ways to treat past data. But that depends on the actual problem.

Comment: the returned type from a call to `fgetc()` is an integer, not a char.  The literal `EOF` is an integer (usually with a value of -1)  If your compiler has `char` as unsigned, then the comparison between char and EOF will fail.  Strongly suggest changing this: `char c;` to this `int c;`  (2 places) everything else will not need to be changed.

Comment: the call to `getLineCount()` would be massively faster if you used something similar to: `ret = 0;  char *lineptr = NULL; size_t n=0;  while( getline( &lineptr, &n, stdin) ) { ret++; }`  if you keep each returned `lineptr` in an array of lineptr,  then the whole input could be kept in one pass.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind multiplying the number of newlines by 18. I also don't understand why you're allocating an array of integers and then casting it to a `char*` pointer. However, if you want to store the contents of a file of unknown length, it would be better to start with a small array, then use `realloc()` to request more space as needed (typically doubling the allocated size each time).

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage It's just a part of the full code. I removed unnecessary rows from it. That was a memory allocation for a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rewind(stdin)` to set the stream back to the start of file, but be aware that it is not guaranteed to work, especially if the stream is a pipe, a terminal or a device.

Your allocation scheme is incorrect: you could compute the size of the file and then allocate that many bytes, but your current `(char*)calloc(lineNum * 18,sizeof(int));` allocates 18 times the size of type `int` for each line. Some files with short lines will fit in this array while others will invoke undefined behavior.

Note that `c` must be defined as `int` for `c = fgetc(stdin);` to properly store all values including the `EOF` special value.

Comment: It's just a part of the code(not full), it must be 18 because of the requirements of the solution.

Comment: @DoğaCanYanıkoğlu: `18` what? If lines are fixed width and 18 bytes including the `\n`, you should allocate `calloc(lineNum * 18,1)`

Comment: It's a 2D String array. 18 is the words' length and it has 1 character in every memory cell. @chqrlie

Comment: @DoğaCanYanıkoğlu: why `sizeof(int)` then?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `rewind`.

You can, of course, save the data you read from stdin (potentially in a file if it's too large for main memory) and operate on that.

Another possibility is this:

```
struct callback {
  void (*call) (char, void *);
  void * data;
};

void with_characters_from(FILE * file, struct callback const * callbacks, size_t count) {
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    char character = c & 0xFF;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      callbacks[i].call(character, callbacks[i].data);
    }
  }
}
```

You inverse control, such that no longer your functions are "pulling data out of" stdin, but rather the data (characters) are "pushed to" them. Note that this can lead to callback hell, and in C you sacrifice a good portion of type safety (as well as code clarity .. no first class functions / closures ... sigh).

[A small test](http://ideone.com/uaXURg):

```
struct counter_data {
  char const character;
  unsigned count;
};

void counter (char character, void * vptr) {
  struct counter_data * data = vptr;
  if (character == data->character) {
    ++(data->count);
  }
}

int main() {
  struct counter_data data [2] = {
    {'a', 0}, {'x', 0}};
  struct callback callbacks [2] = {
    {&counter, &(data [0])},
    {&counter, &(data [1])}};
  with_characters_from (stdin, callbacks, 2);
  printf("Counted %c %u times \n", data [0].character, data [0].count);
  printf("Counted %c %u times \n", data [1].character, data [1].count);
  return 0;
}
```

As already noted, for your particular example, you should consider a completely different approach: If possible compute the required size beforehand. If you exceed that size (which you should always test for), then use `realloc` in order to get a larger chunk of memory.